# How does h2o.cor deal with categorical data

Tags: h2o

h2o.cor function is very powerful because it deals with categorical data, however, on h2o's kmeans function, that also only traditionally deal with numerical data, allows you to specify the categorical_encoding used - how does the h2o.cor function deal with categorical data?

Answer (score 0):

For H2O-3 version 3.22 and earlier the `h2o.cor()` function is only meant to be applied to numeric type columns (so it doesn't handle categorical columns). If you try to run `h2o.cor()` on categorical columns it should return NA (the exception being a binary column, because it can be mapped to numeric 0/1).